# Delphi 10.4.2 and IOS SDK 15.2

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi 10.4.2 and have done an iOS SDK update to version 15.2.

I am using a server in MacInCloud with macOS Monterey to compile.

During compilation I get the following error:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FC:UserDocumentsEmbarcaderoStudioSDKsSystemLibraryPrivateFrameworksDocumentManager.framework'
  ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture arm64
[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

What can be done about it ?

Comment: Probably updating to Delphi 11 or reverting back to older SDK and macOS. Monterey was released after Delphi 11 and there was additional patch available to support it. Generally, upgrade macOS and iOS SDK only when updating Delphi - watch for officially supported versions. Apple makes frequent changes to their building/linking/signing process and that often breaks Delphi.

Comment: Thanks. I have Xcode version 13.1, 13.2, 13.2.1 on my server. Is there any way on Delphi side to select Xcode version for my compilation ?

Comment: "Is there any way on Delphi side to select Xcode version for my compilation ?". No. Use the xcode-select command on the Mac

Comment: @DaveNottage   Sorry for the stupid question. I never select xCode or run to cimpiltion. I assume that on the server is implicitly some version active. How then can I choose the version ? Is it set somewhere on the MAC ?

Comment: By default, Xcode just updates to whichever is the latest version, however you can install earlier versions in another location. xcode-select allows you to make one of the other versions the "default". Incidentally, if you're planning to deploy to the App Store, it is wise to use the latest version of Delphi. By this April, it won't be possible to use Delphi 10.4.x to deploy to the App Store.

Comment: For now, I don't plan to implement in the store. There is not yet a component for version 11 that I need. Where exactly is the default SDK version set, on the mac ?

Comment: I found where this is set up. Thank you for your help !!